# How to restrict Date fields to select past dates in Alfresco Process Servicce?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am quite new to Alfresco Process Service, I have one workflow due date field on metadata form but now it's allowing users to select past dates also, but workflow due date will never be past date.

I also wan't to restrict users to select Saturday's & Sunday's which are holidays.

And if possible, I also want to restrict users to select public holidays.(It's ok if we can provide the hard coded list of public holidays)

Please suggest the possible ways to do this, also share any code snippet if it only possible through some customization.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala      We are using Alfresco Process Service 1.9 version

Comment: create your custom field from form-stencil and add it to your start-form